# Timer, TimerTask and battery consumption

Tags: android, timer, timertask, battery

Assume there is a **large** set of reminders, and every reminder stores time when it should go off in long format.

What is more efficient from power consumption point of view:

1. Create `TimerTask` **for every reminder**, even there are **many** reminders, and put these `TimerTask` instances to the `Timer` process to control when they should go off.
2. Have **one scheduled** `TimerTask` process that runs *every minute* over this list of reminders and compares current time in milliseconds with the reminder's time in long format. And when it is necessary, it shows alarm according to the reminder.

At the first glance, the second approach should consume more power and drain the battery much more faster.

Am I right, or making many (100, 200, or even more) `TimerTask` instances and putting them to `Timer` via `schedule` or other relevant method will drain the battery faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the AlarmManager class. It much better way than others.

Read the official document regarding AlarmManager [here](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)

Comment: There is also a cwac-wakeful pattern available which is using that AlarmManager in an efficient way.